# Enforcing request params validation for flask routes

Tags: python, flask

Consider the following case where I have a specific route and corresponding controller
And based on the request params I need to perform some validations and then complete
the request.

Now in future team might add lots of new routes and respective controllers
How can I enforce they always add validation on parameters?

```
@app.route("/do_something", methods=['GET'])
def lets_do_something():
    MyController.lets_do_something()

class MyController(object):

    def lets_do_something():
        model_id = request.args.get("model_id", 0)

    # diffferent validation specific to user and model_id
```

Comment: What does the validation look like? What is the purpose of `MyController`? Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Validations are specific to user and model. e.g If user is allowed to access the given instance. If yes what are the attributes he is allowed to modify

Answer (score 1):

You could create a decorator that does the validation logic. 
So for each new route you or someone from the team creates, you only need to add the decorator (in the code example 'custom_decorator' )

```
    @custom_decorator
    @app.route("/do_something", methods=['GET'])
    def lets_do_something():
        MyController.lets_do_something()

    class MyController(object):

        def lets_do_something():
            model_id = request.args.get("model_id", 0)

# diffferent validation specific to user and model_id
```

For info on creating decorators see these links

http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/